# Gradle for JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, gradle

Is there a gradle plugin that will work with JBoss 7 deployments? Found a github project that hasn't been committed to in 6 months, and the instructions were off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Gradle Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) provides support for [JBoss 7 deployments](http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+7.x).

**EDIT:**

Gradle is a general-purpose build automation tool. Therefore, there's no restriction on what you can automate. While Cargo works fine for deploying web apps to testing environments, I would not use Cargo for production deployments. For production deployments you will probably want more sophisticated behavior like shutting down the server, archiving the existing artifact, copying the new one and bringing up the server. Also, you might want to look into rolling deployments and version rollbacks. [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) is a tool that provides deployment capabilities.

Comment: Thanks.  Cargo is what I was looking for to test simple JBoss deployments.  Hadn't head of Capistrano.  There are a lot of tools popping up in this category.